# Find the eigenvalues ​and eigenfunctions of the Sturm-Liouville problem $x^4 y'' + k^2 y = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, eigenfunctions, sturm-liouville

Find the eigenvalues ​​and eigenfunctions of the Sturm-Liouville problem

$x^4 y'' + k^2 y = 0$
$y(\alpha) = y(\beta) = 0$, $\hspace{0.4cm}0 < \alpha < \beta$

For this problem I need to find the eigenvalues ​​and the eigenfunctions. Originally the problem has variable coefficients, so I think I can transform the problem to the form $v'' + k^2 v = 0$. I think this is possible by doing a change of variable, which one? I'm familiar with problems that have the form $y'' + \lambda y = 0$. In these cases, to find the eigenvalues ​​and eigenfunctions is simply to consider the cases where $\lambda <0$ or $\lambda = 0$ or $\lambda> 0$. However, I have had difficulty finding the eigenvalues ​​and eigenfunctions for this problem posed here. How can I do this? I appreciate any help

Answer (score 3):

$$x^4 y'' + k^2 y = 0$$
$$x^2 y'' + \dfrac {k^2}{x^2} y = 0$$
Z Ahmed's answer is correct substitute $w=\dfrac 1x$:
$$y'=-w^2\dfrac {dy}{dw}$$
$$y''=2w^3 \dfrac {dy}{dw}+w^4 \dfrac {d^2y}{dw^2}$$
The DE becomes:
$$wy''+2y'+k^2wy=0$$
$$(wy)''+k^2wy=0$$
Which is the form  you wanted:
$$v''+k^2v=0$$
Where $v=wy=\dfrac yx$.

Answer (score 2):

Check that
$$y''+(k^2/x^4)y=0$$ has two real linearly independent solutions as $y=x\sin(k/x), x \cos(k/x)$. So its general solytion is given as $$y(x)=x(C_1 \sin(k/x)+C_2\cos(k/x)).$$ The conditions $y(a)=0=y(b)$ give
$C_1\sin(k/a)+C_2 \cos(k/b)=0,$ $C_1 \sin(k/b)+ C_2 \cos(k/b))=0$.
By comparing $C_1/C_2$ from these equations, we get the eigenvalues as
$$\tan(k/a)-\tan(k/b)=0 \implies \sin [k(b-a)/(ab)] =\implies k_n=\frac{n\pi ab}{b-a},(b>a), n=1,2,3,4,..$$

Comment: @Aryadeva Argument of sign and cos is $(k/x)$ only, please check again.

Comment: Yeah you are correct Ahmed.

Comment: @ZAhmed Does this allow us to conclude that the eigenfunctions have the form $$y_{n}(x) = A_{n}x\cos\left[\frac{n \pi ab}{(b-a)x}\right] + B_{n}x\sin\left[\frac{n \pi ab}{(b-a)x}\right]$$?